# Monotone+continuous but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a continuous and monotone function that's nowhere differentiable ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No.  Even without the assumption of continuity, a monotone function on $\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable except on a set of measure $0$ (and it can have only countably many discontinuities).  This is mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Some_basic_applications_and_results), and proofs can be found in books on measure theory such as Royden or Wheeden and Zygmund.  You can read the details in the latter book at [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 15):

Even any function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: This is because a function of bounded variation is a difference of monotone functions.

Comment: Yes, it would have been better to start the answer with "More generally" instead of "Even".