# $|f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h')|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow f$ is continuous at a

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

I need to prove or disprove that if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $h,h'\in(-\delta,\delta): |f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h')|<\varepsilon$, then f is continuous at a (f is defined at a).

If the statement is true then I need to prove it, otherwise a counterexample would be enough. I could not find one (thus I believe the statement is true), yet I cannot prove it.

Thank you very much and have a good day!!

Comment: Your condition holds in particular for $h'=0$, therefore ...

Comment: @MartinR Oh! Can't believe I didn't see it, thank you very much!

Comment: Marginally related: [Prove the set of points where $f$ is differentiable is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919366/prove-the-set-of-points-where-f-is-differentiable-is-dense)

Comment: Note that the conclusion is wrong if you the estimate holds  only for $h=h'$.

Comment: @MartinR Correct. I thought of $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ when $f(0)$ is defined to be $0$.