# Difference quotients and Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Is there any example of a function $f$ on $R$ such that
$$\left|\frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) -2f(x)}{h}\right| \leq C$$
for all $x$ and all $h\neq 0 $ but not Lipschitz continuous(Lip$_1$) in $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any discontinous additive function will work because it will have a. graph dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the given quotient is $0$. Read about the construction here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: @Sphere: In fact, [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-117-01/S0002-9939-1993-1146866-8/) shows that there exist **continuous** functions satisfying this property (often called "Zygmund smooth" in the literature) that fail to be pointwise Lipschitz at **each point**. See also my comment to [Prove the set of points where $f$ is differentiable is dense.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919366/13130)