# Right continuous and monotone function must exist right derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Right continuous and monotone function must exist right derivative?

Suppose $f:R\rightarrow R$ is a right continuous and monotone function, i.e. $f(x+)=f(x),\forall x\in R$ and $f(x)$ is monotone, say non-decreasing. Does the limit exist $\lim_{\delta \searrow 0 }\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta}$ everywhere ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a simple counterexample is $\sqrt x$. Another is $x+\sqrt{\max(0,x-1)}$.

Comment: @Ethanabc: hem, you must have a different notion of monotonicity.

Comment: Why the second example does not have right derivative everywhere?

Comment: @Ethanabc. Sorry, it is not. Fixing.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
    x &, x<0 \\
    \sqrt{2x - x^2} &, 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}(2-\sqrt{2}) \\
    x - 1 + \sqrt{2}&, \frac{1}{2}(2-\sqrt{2}) \leq x
\end{cases}$$
is continuous everywhere, strictly monotonically increasing everywhere, and (two-sided) differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus\{0\}$.  At $x = 0$, the left derivative is $1$ and the right derivative is undefined.

What kinds of discontinuities (in $f'$) are there?  Removable, infinite, jump, 
endpoint, essential, and mixed (like $\mathrm{e}^{1/x}$).  Which of these can we make work?  Yves Daoust makes an infinite endpoint discontinuity with $\sqrt{x}$.  I made a mixed discontinuity above.  Essential singularities can be made to work.  (Glue $\int_{-1}^x 1+\sin(1/u) \, \mathrm{d}u$ on $(-\infty,0)$ to $2 - \int_{x}^1 1+\sin(1/u) \, \mathrm{d}u$ on $(0,\infty)$ along $\left( 0,\frac{1}{2} \right)$.)  Infinite discontinuity is easy: glue two quarter circles together (or any other endpoint-like discontinuities).
[image]

Jump isn't strong enough, since you only need a one-sided derivative.  Removable isn't strong enough either.  (What would a Calculus student do with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{x^2}{x}$, starting with either the quotient rule or the definition of the derivative?  We allow cancellation under the limit sign that extends the domain of the resulting expressions.  Of course, *we* remember that the derivative is undefined when the function is undefined...)

Answer (score 3):

Any time you think that continuity might imply something about differentiability, the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is usually a counterexample.

It's continuous and monotone increasing.  But you can check directly that $f(3^{-n}) = 2^{-n}$.  So taking $x=0$ and $\delta = 3^{-n}$, so that $\delta \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, your difference quotient equals $(2/3)^{-n}$ which blows up as $n \to \infty$.  Indeed this function is non-right-differentiable at any point of the Cantor set which is not a "right endpoint".

You can say, however, that every continuous monotone increasing function is (two-sided) differentiable almost everywhere.  See [Monotone+continuous but not differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17069/monotonecontinuous-but-not-differentiable).