# Is there a continuous monotone function that fails to be differentiable on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

My textbook is asking to construct such a function, but [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17069/monotonecontinuous-but-not-differentiable) seems to say that's not possible. What am I missing here? I want to construct a function that's not differentiable for $x=c$, for any $c$ in the interval.

I am referring to part B below: [image: this problem].

Comment: Nowhere differentiable is not the same as being non-differentiable on a dense set.

Comment: Maybe one can do something similar to the [Devil's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)?

Comment: @Arthur The Cantor function is only non-differentiable on the Cantor set, which is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Which is why I didn't post it as an answer. I don't even know if the approach is possible to adapt to a dense set.

Comment: @bob Can you tell from which book you found this excercise?

Comment: @Shubham Understanding Analysis, Abbott, 2nd edition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question to which you have linked discusses the impossibility of constructing a function that is continuous, monotone, and *nowhere* differentiable.  However, you are not being asked to construct such a function.  You are being asked to construct a continuous, monotone function which is non-differentiable on a *dense subset* of $\mathbb{R}$.

My goto example of such a function is a function which has a little "jump" at each rational number.  To build such a function, start by defining
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \ge 0$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
This function has a jump discontinuity at zero.

Next, observe that the rational numbers are countable, which implies that there is a bijection $q : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ which provides an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $q_n := q(n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  At each $n$, we are going to define a function $f_n$ which has a jump discontinuity at $q_n$.  In order to ensure that the function we get doesn't "blow up", we are going to build the jumps in such a way that they get small relatively quickly.  Specifically, define
$$ f_n(x) := \frac{f(x-q_n)}{2^n}. $$
If you prefer something more explicit, note that
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 2^{-n} & \text{if $x \ge q_n$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

Because we have chosen the jumps in such a way that they get small fast, we can sum all of these functions and get something that converges.  So define
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x). $$
It is not *too* hard to show that this function converges pointwise and has a discontinuity at every rational number.

Finally, as per the hint in your homework, define
$$ G(x) = \int_{a}^x g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$
As per the quoted text, $G$ is not differentiable at any rational number.

Note that I have left out quite a few details which you should fill in.  You should make sure that you understand why $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (unless these are facts that you are allowed to take for granted). 
 You should also check that $g$ really is discontinuous at each rational, and you should make sure that you understand why the series defining $g$ actually converges.  Finally, it might be a good idea to build $G$ a little more carefully so that it is more artfully restricted to the interval of interest, i.e. the interval $[a,b]$.

EDIT:  As per the comment left below by Dave L. Renfro, these kinds of results can be pushed farther to obtain, for example, *Lipschitz* continuous monotone functions which are non-differentiable on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  The relevant discussion is contained in [this answer to another question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746930/monotone-function-derivative-limit-bounded-differentiable-2/2747372#2747372).

Comment: Regarding how far such examples can be pushed that also satisfy an additional restriction (namely, being Lipschitz continuous), see my answer to [Monotone Function, Derivative Limit Bounded, Differentiable - 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746930/monotone-function-derivative-limit-bounded-differentiable-2/2747372#2747372).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Nice!