# Existence of a monotonic function that is not differentiable anywhere

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, density-function, monotone-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $F: A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is monotonic.

Must $\dfrac{dF}{dx}$ exist?

I'm wondering about this in the context where $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and want to come up with a pathological CDF that is continuous but not differentiable. This is weird to me, since a CDF is an integral, so the CDF must be differentiable. However, we really define the density as a Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure that induces the CDF, not the other way around.

So must $F$ have a (usual, not RN) derivative?

Comment: It was a long time ago, so I don't remember the details, but I recall seeing a construction of such a function.  It was similar to the Cantor middle third function.

Comment: I was thinking of the Cantor distribution, but its CDF is differentiable (and equal to zero) almost everywhere.

Comment: You are right.  I don't think I can be of further help.

Comment: I believe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17069/monotonecontinuous-but-not-differentiable) post will guide you to finding a proof that such a function cannot exist. Unless maybe your $A$ is particularly disconnected.

Comment: Does a super disconnected $A$ help me for the ultimate goal of having this apply to a CDF?

Comment: No. First, CDF-s are defined on entire $\mathbb{R}$, and second, if $A$ is "super disconnected", e.g. discrete, derivative does not even make sense since the difference quotients are not defined at nearby points.

Comment: As Conifold pointed out, your ultimate goal is impossible, because CFDs are by definition defined on all of $\mathbb R$. For your title question, the only counterexample would necessarily be defined on some set with no interior, for example $\mathbb Q$, and then you would have to redefine your definition of derivative to make sense in the subspace topology, and proceed from there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function  May be of some help.  However monotone requirement could be a problem.

Comment: @Dave http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun A cdf is differentiable almost everywhere.